# Question regarding elasticity and deformation

Tags: classical-mechanics, elasticity

Say I apply a deforming force (elongation to be specific) of 10N there is a restoring force of 10N. Now I apply additional 1N and there is elongation in direction of force because $fnet$ is in that direction and there is acceleration but now the body applies a restoring force of 1N and there is an equilibrium condition. My question is that when there was an acceleration and Fnet became 0 shoudnt it continue elongating with constant velocity and not remain at rest in its elongated position?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/689949/2451

Comment: I read the answers on the link sent but I want to know why it remains at rest in its place and not why it returns.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity assume a horizontal spring & mass system.

With a force of $10\,\rm N$ applied assume the elongation of the spring is $1 \,\rm m$ and the energy stored in the spring is $\frac 12 k e^2 = \frac 12 \cdot\frac {10}{1}\cdot 1^2 = 5\,\rm J$.

Now apply an extra force of $1\rm N$ in addition to the $10\, \rm N$, so the total force is now $11\,\rm N$ and move that force $0.11\,\rm m$ so that the mass is in the new **static** equilibrium position with no net force on it.

The total energy stored in the spring is now $\frac 12 \cdot 10 \cdot 1.1^2 = 6.05\rm \, J$ and so the extra energy gained by the spring when extended a further $0.1\,\rm m$ is $6.05-5=1.05\,\rm J$.

The work done by the $11\,\rm N$ force in extending the spring an extra $0.1\,\rm m$ is $11\cdot 0.1= 1.1 \,\rm J$.

This means that the work done by the $11\,\rm N$ force in extending the spring by $0.1\,\rm m$ is greater that the extra energy stored in the spring by $1.1 - 1.05 = 0.05 \,\rm J$.

If there was no friction then that difference in energy is equal to the kinetic energy of the mass as it passes through a new **static** equilibrium position.
At that position reducing the applied force to $10\,\rm N$ will mean that the mass will slow down, eventually stop and then return back the way it came and execute simple harmonic motion about the "$10\,\rm N$" force static equilibrium position.

Comment: so if at 11N a body has constant velocity and therefore constant deformation because of equilibrium why can't we see it in real life when we deform a rubber band?

Comment: The body does not have constant velocity at any point. Its motion is accelerated.

Comment: when I deform it further I have to apply extra force and fnet is in the direction so there is acceleration and body is in deformation but when restoring force balances it and equilibrium is achieved shouldn't it continue deforming with constant velocity as I already brought it into motion and not stay at rest according to Newton's first law?